# How to format ServiceStack Redis connection string

Tags: redis, servicestack.redis

How can I format the below Redis connection string:

Connection string:
myIP,keepAlive=180,ConnectRetry=30,ConnectTimeout=5000

I started writing a unit test but keep getting a input string was not in correct format error message

```
 [TestFixtureSetUp]
        private void Init()
        {
            var redisConnectionString = "myIP,keepAlive=180,ConnectRetry=30,ConnectTimeout=5000";                
         _clientsManager = new PooledRedisClientManager(redisConnectionString);

        }

        [Test]
        public void CanConnectToRedis()
        {
            var readWrite = (RedisClient) _clientsManager.GetClient();
            using (var redis = _clientsManager.GetClient())
            {
                var redisClient = redis;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

See the connection string format on the [ServiceStack.Redis home page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-connection-strings):

```
redis://localhost:6379?ConnectTimeout=5000&IdleTimeOutSecs=180
```

Which can be used in any of the [Redis Client Managers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-client-managers):

```
var redisManager = new RedisManagerPool(
    "redis://localhost:6379?ConnectTimeout=5000&IdleTimeOutSecs=180");
using (var client = redisManager.GetClient())
{
    client.Info.PrintDump();
}
```

The list of [available configuratoin options are also listed on the homepage](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-connection-strings).

Comment: This returns an input string with incorrect format error.var redisConnectionString = "redis://localhost:6379?ConnectTimeout=5000&IdleTimeOutSecs=180";

Comment: @user1526912 I just added working code above. If you're not already upgrade to the latest version of the ServiceStack Redis Client.

Comment: I am using ServiceStack version 4.030319 and stil encountering this error